# Google Scripts function not doing anything (Google Script tied to Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code on a dice roller sheet I'm trying to make. In column 1, I'm putting the number of dice being used, in column 3, I'm putting the type of dice used (d4 is 4, d6 is 6, d8 is 8, etc.), in column 5, I'm putting the interior modifier (mod for every dice), and in column 7, I'm putting the outside modifier (overall modifier after everything is rolled).

In column 9, everything is supposed to be consolidated as shown in the code below... But nothing's happening on the sheet itself.

Note: No listed errors, it seems to be running properly, but nothing's being displayed.

Quick edit, just for completeness' sake, I replaced all instances of " with ', nothing happened, which I figured, but I'm a bit new haha

```
function onEdit() { // Column 7
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Spreadsheet
  var sheeta = "Rolls";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheeta); // Active sheet

  var numberrange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  numberrange = (numberrange.getRow(),1);

  var typerange = (numberrange.getRow(),3);

  var modrange = (numberrange.getRow(),5);

  var outermodrange = (numberrange.getRow(),7);

  var finalrange = (numberrange.getRow(),9);

  var results = "=" + numberrange.getValue() +"*(TRUNC(RAND()*(" + typerange.getValue() + "-1)+" + modrange.getValue() + "))+" + outermodrange.getValue(); // =1*(TRUNC(RAND()*(6-1)+0))+0

  finalrange.setValue(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is not range `numberrange = (numberrange.getRow(),1);` rather this is just a (X,Y).
   I don't know why you didn't mentioned, I think you must be getting error while executing the script.
   To convert this into range you should do something like `numberrange = sheet.getRange(numberrange.getRow(),1);`
2. Here `finalrange.setValue(results);` results is a formula I guess, so kindly use `finalrange.setFormula(formula)` function.

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue or if you have any doubt.

Comment: Your first point worked perfectly, thank you! The second one, I've been using setValue because I'm adding several different strings together into a formula. It works, don't know if setFormula would also work though.